# Login Problem on Stack Overflow with IE11 and Stack Exchange Account

Tags: bug, login, internet-explorer

Since a couple of days Stack Overflow does not log me in automatically any more. Stack Exchange however does. Clicking on "login" from the Stack Overflow start page throws me immediately back to the start page without logging me in. Clicking on "signup"; however, does log me in (without me having to enter anything on this page).

I tried debugging the problem with the F12 Developer Tools, however clicking on "login" closes these tools immediately.

With Firefox everything is fine.

Does anybody have an idea what's going on?

Comment: I just tried but I can't repro. Are you using a Google or a Stack Exchange account? Can you try with InPrivate browsing?

Comment: I am using a Stack Exchange account. Same problem with InPrivate brwosing. I also cleared the cookies, temporary internet files and browse history. It did not make any difference.

Comment: Any plugins installed lately?

Comment: No new ones; however, some were updated: Shockwave Flash Object is pretty new. But disabling it does not help.

Comment: Running IE in the [no add-ons mode](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/run-internet-explorer-8-in-no-add-ons-mode) does mode does not help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by running IE11 as administrator. Clicking on "signup" did not log me in automatically as previously. Here I entered my (existing) user name, e-mail address and password. Now the automatic login to my existing account works again.

Note: I was still not able to click on "login", as explained in the question.